# Using google drive to host my jquery mobile webapp: why is the viewport zoomed out on iphone?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, url-rewriting, google-drive-api, viewport

My problem is with display of my webapp. I would like to use google drive to host my webapp (j query mobile) so I can test it out. I followed the google drive instructions and uploaded my index.html, my js folder and my css folder to a public shared folder on my gdrive. The test site displays well on the iOS Simulator only if I load the index.html directly from my google drive folder on my laptop. But if the index.html is loaded from the web, the page appears very zoomed out (but otherwise functional). The site is http://gdriv.es/whatname

I have the viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui"
The jquery and jquery mobile js is hosted on a CDN if that is relevant.

I have tried copying all files from another jquery mobile site which I have hosted elsewhere and which I know displays well on iphone etc - but interestingly it also displays this zoomed out behaviour on google drive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not in your files, **viewport** is also correct.

Unfortunately your content is shown inside a frame thus your viewport is not taken into consideration. Frame is built to cover available space so you can't see it, unless you view page source.

This is what your final page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>a title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="GDrives whatname on Google Drive Site Publishing web hosting" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="/logo.png" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
             // Here's google and yahoo analytics code
        </script>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="100%">
        <frame src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B5HUb04HaxoSWEtnMVI4TzBmZFk/" />
        <noframes>
            <body>
                <p><a href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B5HUb04HaxoSWEtnMVI4TzBmZFk/">Go to Whatname on Google Drive Site Publishing web hosting</a></p>
            </body>
        </noframes>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Your content is linked here:

```
<frame src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B5HUb04HaxoSWEtnMVI4TzBmZFk/" />
```

Comment: That's good - I get a nice layout on mobile if I use the original path to the content, instead of the url shortening service. Maybe there are url shorteners that don't wrap a frame around everything as another possible solution.